# Why Electric current is considered fundamental quantity

Tags: electricity

It seems to me electric charge is more fundamental than electric current. Can anybody explain why electric current is taken as fundamental quantity and not electric charge?

Answer (score -1):

Units are political. But one who is accustomed to seeing amperes can argue they are easier to use in real life.

Comment: Units are metrological. We chose base units by how well they can be implemented in metrological laboratories. If you can come up with an experiment to define an absolute Coulomb to one part in $10^{14}$, the world will adopt your definition in no time. Can you?